# Enviar email de bienvenida después de registro - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-blade

espero estén todos bien.

Estoy teniendo problemas para que mi aplicación web hecha en Laravel envié un email al usuario que se registre, Hice todo lo que la documentación de Laravel dice, pero evidentemente algo esta mal en mi código por que no envía ningún email.

Me registre en Mailgun y configure .env con los datos requeridos, cree el controlador con pphp artisan make:mail Wellcome y configure:

```
        <?php
   namespace App\Mail;

     use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable; use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable; use 
    Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels; use 
    Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

     class Wellcome extends Mailable { use Queueable, SerializesModels;

     /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('wellcome')
            ->from('info.venexcargoutah@gmail.com')
            ->subject('Bienvenido!');
}
}
```

También configure el controllador de registro agregándole el envió del email:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    isset($data['user_pic']) ? $photoPath = $data['user_pic']->store('public/userPhotos') : $photoPath = 'userPhotos/login.png';

   return User::create([
     'name' => $data['name'],
     'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
     'email' => $data['email'],
     'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
     'direction' => $data['direction'],
     'zone' => $data['zone'],
     'phone' => $data['phone'],
     'user_pic' => $photoPath,
   ]);

   **Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Welcome($user));**

}
public function showRegistrationForm()
 {
   return view('register');
 }
}
```

Y por ultimo el blade con la vista del email:

```
@include('layouts.head')

<div class="">
  <h2>Bienvenido {{ $user->name }}!</h2>

  <p>Esperemos que nuestra aplicación te sea de gran utilidad!</p>

  <h4>Codigo de descuento</h4>


  Enviado automáticamente desde <a href={{ url('venexcargoutah.com') }} title="VenexCargo Utah">VenexCargo Utah</a>
</div>
```

Aun así después del registro exitoso no envía el email ni arroja error alguno. Agradecería de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: en el return el controlador es hasta donde va a llegar, si pasas algo despues del return no va a leer esa linea o en este caso el mail, intenta ponerlo antes, o hacer una validacion con if()

Comment: Si el tema es que hice ambas cosas y nada no envía el mail, se registra genial, pero no envía el mail.

Comment: Igual puedes crear un evento para que se dispare al registrar un usuario

Answer (score 1):

Como ya bien dice el comentario de [Dohko19](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/91549/dohko19)
El return en tu controlador esta antes del llamado a la funcion `Mail`

Puedes mover tu funcion antes del `return` o crear el objeto user y ese valor retornar:

```
  $user =  User::create([
          'name' => $data['name'],
          'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
          'email' => $data['email'],
          'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
          'direction' => $data['direction'],
          'zone' => $data['zone'],
          'phone' => $data['phone'],
          'user_pic' => $photoPath,
  ]);

Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Welcome($user));
return $user;
```

Comment: Si eso entendí, también eso hice antes de consultar,  para probar, el tema es que así me tira error 500, por que al registrar se redirecciona al usuario a una pagina de bienvenida que solo vera después del registro, al hacer lo que indicas me tira error, me registra bien, por que se carga en la base de datos, pero queda en la pagina de bienvenida con error.

Comment: deberias de hacer un dd o algun return antes para ver que esta pasando

Comment: Todo esto lo estas haciendo en tu local? Tienes habilitado algún servidor de correo local?
En lo personal te recomiendo usar este http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/